# Getting a client readable message from an Npgsql.PostgresException

Tags: asp.net-core, ef-code-first, npgsql

I'm writing a web api using PostgreSQL and am checking database constraints as part of the validation process, but I also have a global exception filter as a fallback in case something gets by when saving.  My problem is that the exception doesn't seem to have any message that I can present to the client without some processing.  The added image is of the PostgresException data from a breakpoint.  For example, in this case I would want something along the lines of "Asset Number x already exists" or just "Asset Number must be unique".  Is this something that can be configured somewhere?  The place that makes the most sense is at the constraint creation code, but I couldn't find an option to do so.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AssetItem>().HasIndex(item => new { item.AssetNumber }).IsUnique();

public class DbExceptionFilter : IExceptionFilter 
{
    private const string UNIQUE_EXCEPTION = "23505";
    public async void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        var exceptionType = context.Exception.InnerException.GetType().FullName;

        if (exceptionType == "Npgsql.PostgresException")
        {
            var pgException = (PostgresException) context.Exception.InnerException;

            switch(pgException.SqlState)
            {
                case UNIQUE_EXCEPTION:
                    var error = new {error = "Unique Error Here"};
                    await WriteJsonErrorResponse(context.HttpContext.Response, HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, error);
                    return;
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            var error = new { error = "Unexpected Server Error"};
            await WriteJsonErrorResponse(context.HttpContext.Response, HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, error);
            return;
        }
    }

    private async Task WriteJsonErrorResponse(HttpResponse response, HttpStatusCode statusCode, dynamic error)
    {
        response.ContentType = "application/json";
        response.StatusCode = (int) statusCode;
        await response.Body.WriteAsync(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(error)));
    }
}
```

[image: Exception Properties]

Comment: Isn't the message text of the PostgresException saying exactly what you need? You also have the other fields if you need to access the information programmatically (e.g. SqlState 23505 means unique constraint violation). What's missing here?

Comment: From the exception filter I want to return a response to the api consumer, and these messages don't seem suitable for that. Not that there would be much confusion if I used, say, the Detail field since it's pretty understandable. I figure the same error sent in the response would be presented to the client application end user. Even then, at least in this case, I think it would be understandable to that end user, but the message seems like it's suited more towards whatever is accessing the database, and not the user of the api.  Am I trying to get the data layer to do something it shouldn't?

Comment: I was using the SqlState to figure out what kind of exception it was, but I didn't know how to provide an end user readable message.  Updated with the exception filter code for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing to a user-readable message that PostgreSQL provides is the message text exposed on PostgresException.

However, as a general rule it is not a good idea to expose database errors directly to users (including web API users): these are intended to the application directly interacting with the database (i.e. your application). These messages generally don't mean much to the users of your API, and more importantly they leak potentially sensitive information about your database schema and are therefore not secure. It's especially problematic to dump/serialize the entire exception to the user as you seem to be doing (with JsonConvert.SerializeObject).

The best practice here would be to identify legitimate database exceptions that the user may trigger, intercept these and return and appropriately-worded message of your own (e.g. "A user with that name already exists").

As a side note, to identify PostgresException, rather than getting the name of the exception and comparing to that, you can simply use C# pattern matching:

```cs
if (context.Exception.InnerException is PostgresException postgresException)
{
    // ...
}
```